# Extract data from a DF every 5min from the last 400 seconds and elaborate it for creating a new DF

Tags: python, pandas

I am in trouble on extrating from a dataset, the index of which is a datetime down to milliseconds granularity, every 5 minutes (for example) data of previous 400 seconds (for example) and elaborate this data for creating a new DF each row of which have 5 minutes distance from the previous and the next one and new columns/features.

The data I have it is ticks data like this

```
Timestamp,Bid price,Ask price,Bid volume,Ask volume
2022-09-19 00:00:00:710,3876.152,3876.652,0.00044000000343658,0.000119999996968545
2022-09-19 00:00:00:761,3875.942,3876.652,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:01:033,3875.949,3876.364,0.00044000000343658,0.000119999996968545
2022-09-19 00:00:01:084,3875.636,3876.367,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:01:190,3875.851,3876.351,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:01:241,3875.845,3876.501,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:01:865,3875.936,3876.563,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:01:925,3875.942,3876.661,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:02:971,3876.034,3876.655,0.00044000000343658,0.000119999996968545
2022-09-19 00:00:03:022,3876.054,3876.761,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:03:072,3876.142,3876.864,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:06:035,3876.454,3876.848,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:06:085,3876.451,3877.146,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:07:302,3876.699,3877.103,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:07:353,3876.651,3877.349,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:08:147,3876.954,3877.303,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:08:198,3876.942,3877.649,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:09:018,3876.937,3877.558,0.00044000000343658,0.000119999996968545
2022-09-19 00:00:09:068,3876.842,3877.552,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:09:602,3876.945,3877.569,0.00270000007003546,3.99999998990097E-06
2022-09-19 00:00:09:653,3876.933,3877.664,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
2022-09-19 00:00:09:763,3876.642,3877.352,0.00270000007003546,0.00270000007003546
```

I have tried to adapt some examples I found in other posts using the function df.resample('5min').agg(...) but this seems to operate on the same df and to be not useful for creating a new DF, with new columns obtained with custom functions. Here my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lombscargle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('SP500.csv')
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
df.set_index("Timestamp", inplace=True)
candles = df.resample('5min').agg({
                                        "MEAN":  "mean",
                                        "HIGH":  "max",
                                        "LOW":   "min",
                                    })
```

This was just an attempt to see if the approach was working, the need is to replace the inbuilt functions mean, high, low with custom ones.

The expected DF output will be something of similar to the following

- column Timestamp: 2022-09-19 00:00:00:000, 2022-09-19 00:05:00:000, 022-09-19 00:10:00:000, ....
- column Mean: the mean of the bid (or ask) values calculated in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:00:00:000, in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:05:00:000, ....
- column High: the max of the bid (or ask) values in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:00:00:000, in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:05:00:000, 2022-09-19 00:10:00:000, ....
- column Low: the min of the bid (or ask) values in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:00:00:000, in the previous 400 seconds of 2022-09-19 00:05:00:000, 2022-09-19 00:10:00:000, ....

Cannot provide a real calculation since I still have not the tool.

Any suggestion or reference to a pertinent document or example is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

I moved on making this attempt

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('SP500.csv')
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f")
df.head(2)
```

that gives this structure

[image]

Then I created a new DF where I would like to store the elaborations on the original df and created a datetime column the values of which are increased by 5 minutes each one

```
statistics = pd.DataFrame()
statistics['Timestamp'] = pd.date_range(start='19/09/2022', periods=646289, freq ='5min')
statistics.head(5)
```

[image]

Now I would like to create and calculate the column "Bid mean" on "statistics", each row of which is the mean of the previous 400 seconds with respect the Timestamp datetime of the same "statistics" row

```
statistics['Bid Mean'] = df.loc[((df['Timestamp'] < statistics['Timestamp']) & (df['Timestamp'] > statistics['Timestamp'] - pd.Timedelta(seconds=400)))]['Bid price'].mean()
```

Regretefully, what I get is something that does not variate as if statistics['Timestamp'] was constant for each considered row of statistics

[image]

So the questions could be

1. What is wrong with statistics['Timestamp'] that does not change per each considered row?
2. Is there a more concise/elegant way to do what expected?
3. How could be grabed the whole subset of df from timestamp to timestamp in a custom function?

Comment: This question will be much easier to answer if you include an intended/expected output.

Comment: @Dacromir  thank you for your suggestion i have provided a description of the expected result